# Why python read text files show lots of strange characters

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've uploaded text files in python, but it showed below strange characters:

```
[                                                      0
 0                           501000 ��������LOF ���� ��Ȩ
 1           Date\tOpen\tHigh\tLow\tClose\tVolume\tPrice
 2     2015/09/02\t1.003\t1.009\t1.001\t1.001\t10900\...
 3     2015/09/07\t1.008\t1.008\t1.001\t1.007\t25600\...
 4     2015/09/08\t1.000\t1.007\t1.000\t1.007\t4400\t...
 ...                                                 ...
 1702  2023/10/27\t0.778\t0.787\t0.778\t0.787\t400\t3...
 1703  2023/10/30\t0.785\t0.793\t0.785\t0.792\t1100\t...
 1704  2023/10/31\t0.792\t0.792\t0.782\t0.792\t500\t3...
 1705    2023/11/01\t0.792\t0.792\t0.792\t0.792\t0\t0.00
 1706                                      ������Դ:ͨ����
 
 [1707 rows x 1 columns]]
```

What's more, the space in the text file shows up "\t" in the text file, how to delete them?

Thank you.

Comment: `'\t'` are "tab" characters to start... [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Encoding issues? Without knowing the exact contents of the file, or the code used to display it, it's impossible to say anything for certain, only guess (badly).

Answer (score 0):

The "\t" is as @Julien mentioned it is a tab a kind of delimiter to separate values. And the strange question marks are encoding issues as @Some programmer dude described. It is difficult to understand without your sample code and data.